# 412 precondition failed no response

Tags: http-status-code-412

Hi I'm trying to retrieve the json response from my API but I'm having problem if the status code is 412. It just keeps on loading and no response is being returned. But if I change the code to 400 it returns the output successfully. Any reason for this?